# access react component's own instance in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Guys I'm trying to attach a listener to my react component (ModalAddElement && ModalEditElement) and till now I was doing it with jQuery but I'm lookin for the React's way of doing it.I have two instances of my parent component.Here's my component:

```
var DiaryTable = React.createClass({displayName: "DiaryTable",
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            items : this.props.item,
            globalChecked:false,
            checkedCounter:this.props.checkedCounter
        };
    },


onWheelHandler:function (e) {
      e.bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
            var evt = window.event || e;
            evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt;
            var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail * (-40) : evt.wheelDelta;
            if (delta > 0) {
                this.value = parseInt(this.value) + 1;
            }
            else {
                this.value = parseInt(this.value) - 1;
            }
        });
    },

    .... more code here

    render: function(){
            var arrayItems =  this.state.items.map(function (item,i) {
                return (
                    <tr key={i}>
                        <td><input type="checkbox"  checked={item.selected} onClick={this.handleChecked.bind(this,i)}/></td>
                        <td><FormattedDate value={item.start}/></td>
                        <td><FormattedDate value={item.end}/></td>
                        <td className="editable">{Number(item.hours)}</td>
                        <td>
                            <ModalEditElement items={this.state.items} onEditElement={this.handleEditElement} index={i} checked={this.state.globalChecked} ></ModalEditElement>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                );
            }.bind(this));
            return (
                <table className="myTable">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" onClick={this.checkAll} checked={this.state.globalChecked}/></th>
                        <th>Start Date:</th>
                        <th>End Date:</th>
                        <th id="hoursField">Hours:</th>
                        <th id="editField">Edit:</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {arrayItems}
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colSpan="4">
                            <span className="addButtonDisplay"><ModalAddElement onWheel={this.onWheelHandler} onAddElement={this.handleAddElement} items={this.state.items} checked={this.state.globalChecked} ></ModalAddElement></span>
                            <button className="myButton" onClick={this.remove}>Remove period</button>
                            <button className="myButton" disabled={this.props.result.item.length === 0} onClick={this.setResult}>Set result from merge</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            );
        }
     });
```

So what should I use in order to replace 'jQuery(document.body.children[0].children[0])' ?Can I match both istances of DiaryTable I need the listener to apply for ModalAddElement && ModalEditElement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [react event system](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html).

React will created SyntheticEvents instances for you, these instances are a cross-browser wrapper around the browser's native event and they offer you the same interface as the browser's native events.

In react you can attach an event by passing it as a prop with the correct event name. In your case the event name is [onWheel](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#wheel-events).

You can attach the event to what you render in you're component, for example imagine that you're rendering a div, the code to attach the event would be something like this.

```
<div onWheel={this.onWheelHandler}>
...
</div>
```

You're handler will receive the SyntheticEvent as a parameter and you can do something like this

```
onWheelHandler: function (e) {
  var evt = window.event || e
  evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt;
  var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail * (-40) : evt.wheelDelta
  if (delta > 0) {
     this.value = parseInt(this.value) + 1;
  }
  else {
     this.value = parseInt(this.value) - 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: But then in onWheelHandler... I need to specify something different than jQuery selector what it should be ?

Comment: What do you mean? You don't need the selector for anything, the SyntheticEvent that you receive as a prop has everything you will need.

Comment: you haven't understood the way react attaches events yet, e.bind('mousewheel') doesn't exist in react context, see my edit on the original answer

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kwrju6uv/ .In ModalAddElement I have a input type number that  I need my scroll to be  workin on it , should I implement this event handler inside ModalAddElement also ?

Comment: It doesn't work because you are not attaching the onWheel to any element, it wouldn't work for free, have you read react docs like I pointed out?

Comment: I got it , thanks a lot !! Although there isn't much info about implementation  only about type of events.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121933/discussion-between---and-diogo-cunha).